# Android make sure listview is complete visible when expanded

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Following situation: I have a ListFragment, if you click on a list item of it some views inside the list item gets visible, so the list item itself gets expanded. Now, imagine the pressed list item is the last in the list, the expanded part won't be visible. Is there a way to achieve that the list scrolls down a little bit so the complete list item is visible?

Comment: what have you used ? post some code or screenshot of your device..

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `yourListView.scrollTo(0, yourListView.getHeight());`